# How to extract parrticular value from nested json values.?

Tags: python, json, django, mongodb

I am new to python.

I have small requirement (i.e) want to extract only one value from the JSON format.

Please do correct me if i am wrong.

JSON input is:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "limit": 1,
    "next": "/api/v1/ips/?username=sic1&api_key=689db0740ed73c2bf6402a7de0fcf2d7b57111ca&limit=1&objects=&offset=1",
    "offset": 0,
    "previous": null,
    "total_count": 56714
  },
  "objects": [
    {
      "_id": "556f4c81dcddec0c41463529",
      "bucket_list": [],
      "campaign": [
        {
          "analyst": "prabhu",
          "confidence": "medium",
          "date": "2015-06-03 14:50:41.440000",
          "name": "Combine"
        }
      ],
      "created": "2015-06-03 14:50:41.436000",
      "ip": "85.26.162.70",
      "locations": [],
      "modified": "2015-06-18 09:50:51.612000",
      "objects": [],
      "relationships": [
        {
          "analyst": "prabhu",
          "date": "2015-06-18 09:50:51.369000",
          "rel_confidence": "unknown",
          "rel_reason": "N/A",
          "relationship": "Related_To",
          "relationship_date": "2015-06-18 09:50:51.369000",
          "type": "Indicator",
          "value": "556f4c81dcddec0c4146353a"
        }
      ],
      "releasability": [],
      "schema_version": 3,
      "screenshots": [],
      "sectors": [],
      "source": [
        {
          "instances": [
            {
              "analyst": "prabhu",
              "date": "2015-06-03 14:50:41.438000",
              "method": "trawl",
              "reference": "http://www.openbl.org/lists/base_30days.txt"
            }
          ],
          "name": "www.openbl.org"
        }
      ],
      "status": "New",
      "tickets": [],
      "type": "Address - ipv4-addr"
    }
  ]
}
```

The code i used for getting value only IP's from objects

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
import json
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/ips/'
params = {'api_key':'xxxxxx','username': 'abcd'}
r = requests.get(url, params=params, verify=False)
parsed = json.loads(r)
print (parsed['objects']['ip'])
```

The error i am receiving is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testapi.py", line 9, in <module>
    parsed = json.loads(r)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I just want to get IP's from that JSON input.

Thanks.

Comment: You can convert the value of `r` to string by doing this `parsed = json.loads(str(r))`

Comment: @TonyRoczz `str(r)` will convert `<Response 200>` to `'<Response 200>'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line: `parsed = json.loads(r)`

You're reciving the json response but insted of feeding `json` elements to `json.loads` you're instead feeding it `<Response [200]>`

```
    >>> r = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
    >>> r
    <Response [200]>
    >>> type(r)
    <class 'requests.models.Response'>
```

(Look closely at the error message. `Expected string or buffer` Which means you're providing it something that is ***NOT*** string or buffer(an object in this case))
 This is the reason why `str(r)` didn't work. Because it just converted `<Response 200>` to `'<Response 200>'` which obviously is not json.

change this line to `parsed = json.loads(r.text)`.

```
   >>> type(r.text)
   <type 'unicode'>
```

and then `parsed['objects'][0]['ip']` should give you the IP address :)
You can find more about the requests module [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 5):

You are passing a requests object instead of a `str` object to `json.loads()`. You need to change

```
parsed = json.loads(r)
```

to

```
parsed = json.loads(r.text)
```

Also, `parsed['objects']` is a list, you need to access its first element & then get the key `ip`:

```
>>> print(parsed['objects'][0]['ip'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Now its working. one small doubt why we are using `print(parsed['objects'][0]['ip'])` instead of using like this `print(parsed['objects']['ip'])`.

Comment: @TejaR parsed['objects'] is a list, you need to access its first element using `[0]`